# Why doesn't "return x.a;" signal an error?

Tags: java, methods, static

I understand why "return a;" signals an error (because 'a' is non-static attribute and I'm trying to refer to it in a static method), but I don't understand why "return x.a;" doesn't signal an error. The 'a' attribute of 'x' is still non-static, shouldn't it be an error?

```
    class A{
        private int a=0;
        private static int b =0;
    
        public int m(){
            return a;
        }
    
        public static int n(A x){
            return x.a;//not an error
            return a;//error
        }
    }
```

Comment: The method `n` may be static but it's being given an instance `x` which _does_ have the non-static attributes. `return a` is an error because that's not an `int`, nothing to do with static or not.

Comment: What does `a` represent? do you mean the `int a` field?

Comment: Why should it be any different? `a` is not `static` so you can't access it in a static context. `x` is provided as an argument so you can access its fields via the instance

Comment: "*I don't understand why "return x.a;" doesn't signal an error.*" first let us know what makes *you* think that there should be an error here. What is wrong with this code in your opinion? What do you think `static` means?

Comment: `x.a` is the field of the instance `x`. It works because it's a non-static field used with an instance (`x`). In `return a` , `a` is a non-static field, but accessed from a static context (the method `n`).

Comment: `return a` is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I don't understand why "return x.a;" doesn't signal an error

`return x.a` is valid because `x` is accessible as a local variable inside the static method and is an instance of `A`.  `a` is an instance property on the instance of `A` so `x.a` is perfectly valid.